# ItemReader returning a FlatFileItemReader containing entire lines as strings

Tags: java, spring, parsing, spring-batch

Using Spring Batch I am trying to get every line of an input file as a `String` giving it to the `ItemProcessor` without any "CSV parsing" in the `ItemReader`.

I came out with a configuration Java class (using `@Configuration` and `@EnableBatchProcessing`) containing the following `reader()` method which is making the next `ItemProcessor` to throw a `ClassCastException` though.

This `ItemReader` should read an input file and pass to the `ItemProcessor` every line of the input file as a `String`.

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<String> reader() {

    FlatFileItemReader<String> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("data-to-process.txt"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
        setFieldSetMapper(new PassThroughFieldSetMapper());
    }});
    return reader;
}
```

When running the previous code I am getting an exception in the `ItemProcessor` which is expecting a `String` from the `reader()`:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The custom `ItemProcessor` I wrote is defined as:

```
    public class MyOwnCustomItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, MyOwnCustomBusinessBean> {
```

I believe I should use this `PassThroughFieldSetMapper` in the `ItemReader` and I would not like to use any kind of tokenizer. According to the documentation I think I must use it and I can not avoid it, but I am keeping getting exceptions thrown.

How can I "transfer" every input line directly as a `String` to an `ItemProcessor` e.g. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [PassThroughLineMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/PassThroughLineMapper.html) if available else

```
public class PassThroughLineMapper implements LineMapper<String> {
  @Override
  public String mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
    return line;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding also a workaround I found in the meanwhile (using `FieldSet` as a input parameter of the `ItemReader` and the `ItemProcessor`), even if @bellabax provided a better solution.

Check how I used the objects of type `FieldSet`.

The `ItemReader`:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<FieldSet> reader() {

    FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("data-to-process.txt"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
        setFieldSetMapper(new PassThroughFieldSetMapper() {{

        }});

    }});
    return reader;
}
```

The `ItemProcessor` in the Spring Batch Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<FieldSet, MyOwnCustomBusinessBean> processor() {

    return new MyOwnCustomItemProcessor();
}
```

The `ItemProcessor`:

```
public class MyOwnCustomItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<FieldSet, MyOwnCustomBusinessBean> {

    @Override
    public MyOwnCustomBusinessBean process(FieldSet originalInputLineFromInputFile) throws Exception {

        String originalInputLine = originalInputLineFromInputFile.getValues()[0];

        [...]
```